# How to Specify EU Region in Forge-APIs NPM Package for Model Derivative Endpoint?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm using the forge-apis NPM package to interact with the Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API. While I can access the EU region endpoint directly using curl and confirm that it works, I can't find a way to specify the EU region within the forge-apis package. How can I set the region to EU in forge-apis for model derivative requests?

Normally data retrieval via forge-apis is not a problem. For example, the hubs api etc. works fine even though the region is not specified. i only run into this problem when i use the model derivative api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the npm [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-apis), here's how to specify the region :

```
var DerivativesApi = new ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi(); // defaults to US
var DerivativesApi = new ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi(undefined, 'EMEA'); // Use EMEA endpoint
var DerivativesApi = new ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi(undefined, 'EU'); // Use EMEA endpoint
var DerivativesApi = new ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi(undefined, 'US'); // Use US endpoint
```

Both **EU** and **EMEA** target **EU** region.